# Getting the error in Script "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )"

Tags: javascript, cefsharp

While using the CefSharp in method EvaluateScriptAsync (script)
     script is as below

```
 script = @"(function(){var linksArray = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('.g').length; i++)
            {
var elementWithClassRC = document.querySelectorAll('.g')[i].querySelectorAll('.rc');
 var rElement = elementWithClassRC[0].getElementsByClassName('r');
 var sElement= elementWithClassRC[0].getElementsByClassName('s');
 var hrefValue = rElement[0].querySelector('a').getAttribute('href');
 var h3Value = rElement[0].querySelector('a').querySelector('h3').innerHTML;
 var spanValue = sElement[0].querySelector('span').innerText;
 linksArray[i] = [hrefValue,h3Value,spanValue];
 return linksArray;})();";
```

in evaluated Result i am getting the javaScriptResponse.Result as this error ""Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )\n@ about:blank:13:22" ".
    please help me getting this resolved.

Comment: The error is telling you what is wrong. You have a `}` for the `for` loop but none for the enclosing function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing '}' in for loop.

```
script = @"(
       function(){
          var linksArray = new Array();
          for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('.g').length; i++) {
             var elementWithClassRC = document.querySelectorAll('.g')[i].querySelectorAll('.rc');
             var rElement = elementWithClassRC[0].getElementsByClassName('r');
             var sElement= elementWithClassRC[0].getElementsByClassName('s');
             var hrefValue = rElement[0].querySelector('a').getAttribute('href');
             var h3Value = rElement[0].querySelector('a').querySelector('h3').innerHTML;
             var spanValue = sElement[0].querySelector('span').innerText;
             linksArray[i] = [hrefValue,h3Value,spanValue];
          // for loop is not end here
          return linksArray;
  })();";
```

Comment: Thanks ankush for reply!!, after correcting this i am getting the below Error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of undefined

Comment: Because you are not getting anything in elementWithClassRC[0], can you show the html part for which you are calling it.

Comment: i applied null check as well but still i am getting this error, It ia a async method in which this script is excecuting.
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of undefined"

Comment: do not check only for null, you can test something like that  in all required places (elementWithClassRC && elementWithClassRC.length > 0 ? elementWithClassRC[0].getElementsByClassName('r') : null )

Comment: thanks. i am again facing the issue this script is making null result so browser is getting blank. any suggestions please

Comment: if you show your HTML doc, then it will be easy to debug.